# Is it possible to repeat table headers with jQuery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin, which is working really great so far. However my table is quite long so I want to repeat the headers every ~30 rows or so. I tried it and got this alert when I loaded the page:

> DataTables warning: Unexpected number of TD elements. Expected 5230 and got 4980. DataTables does not support rowspan / colspan in the table body, and there must be one cell for each row/column combination.

I changed the cells to TD instead of TH but now they don't stay in place when sorting, for obvious reasons, they just get grouped together. Is there a way round this? DataTables allows custom parsers but I can't think of any way to make every n rows stay in the same position.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to paginate the results? Or does that not work for your implementation?

Comment: @edl: Hmm, I suppose pagination isn't too bad. With the filter and everything it makes it easier for searching and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [fixed header add-on](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/index.html) that works with datatables that you may be interested in.

Comment: Excellent, that works (almost) perfectly! There's a small problem if you add/remove columns or the table moves slightly, but can be worked around by calling the `fixedHeader.fnUpdate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution I think is quite cool: setting a tooltip for appropriate cells with the column title. Perhaps it is overkill, I have ~200 rows and 5 columns that need differentiating, so it's 1000 occurrences of `title="ABC"`. But it works.